# Getting PHP's imap_fetchbody correct part number/index body part list

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments

I'm having difficulty trying to determine how to consistently reference part numbers (a part number such as 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 etc would refer to just the data for a plain/text message, an image/jpeg, etc). Below I'm using `'1.'.$i` and `'2.'.$j` in an attempt to reference objects in a given message. I feel like I'm close though missing something...

> $mbox =
>   imap_open('{mail.example.com:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX','someone+example.com','password');
>
> if ($mbox) {  $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$message_id);
>
> $i = 0;  $j = 0;
>
> foreach ($structure->parts as $k1 => $d1)  {//Next line, how do we
>   refer to the part correct, e.g. "'1.'.$i"?
>
> ```
> if (isset($d1->parts))
> {
>  foreach ($d1->parts as $j2 => $d2)
>  {//Next line, how do we refer to the part correct, e.g. "'2.'.$j"?
>   $a = print_r(imap_fetchbody($mbox,$cms->page2,'2.'.$j),1);
>   echo '<div><img alt="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$a.'" /></div>';
> }}}}
> ```

Also I am not interested in using any frameworks, I want to figure out how to do this myself. I'll be happy to refine my question when asked for relevant clarifications.

Comment: if you look at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) it has all the explanation you need.

Comment: have you found answer, i need it too

Comment: @Wasim I'll post what I found in a few minutes for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before migrating emails to the database I append everything to an `$email` array.

Here is how the iteration over various parts of the email works. There MAY be some older bits in here that I no longer use though this works just fine. Missing functions are what I use to prepare different parts before they are written to the database.

```
   $message = imap_body($mbox,$i);
   $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$i);

   $f = array('!');
   $r = array('');
   $message = str_ireplace($f,$r,$message);
   $find = array('=00');
   $replace = array('');
   $message = str_ireplace($find,$replace,$message);
   $message = mb_convert_encoding($message,'us-ascii','UTF-8');
   $message = utf8_encode($message);

   $dontattach = array('alternative','html','plain','related');
   $ii = 1;
   $j = 1;
   $k = 1;
   $fallback = 0;

   if (isset($structure->parts))
   {
    foreach ($structure->parts as $k1 => $d1)
    {
     if ($d1->subtype=='GIF')
     {
      if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
      if (isset($d1->id)) {$id = $d1->id;} else {$id = '';}
      $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d1->parameters[0]->value,'image/gif',$id);
      array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
     }
     else if ($d1->subtype=='HTML')
     {
      $a = mail_service_html($mbox,$i,$d1->encoding,$d1->parameters[0]->value,$ii,$j);
      if (isset($a['css'])) {$email['css'] = $a['css'];}
      $email['body_xml'] = $a['xml'];
      $fallback++;
     }
     else if ($d1->subtype=='JPEG')
     {
      if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
      if (isset($d1->id)) {$id = $d1->id;} else {$id = '';}
      $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d1->parameters[0]->value,'image/jpeg',$id);
      array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
     }
     else if ($d1->subtype=='PLAIN')
     {
      $a = mail_service_plain($mbox,$i,$d1->encoding,$d1->parameters[0]->value,$ii,$j,$k);
      $email['body_clean'] = $a['xml'];
      $email['body_text'] = $a['plain'];
      $fallback++;
     }
     else if ($d1->subtype=='PNG')
     {
      if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
      if (isset($d1->id)) {$id = $d1->id;} else {$id = '';}
      $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d1->parameters[0]->value,'image/png',$id);
      array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
     }
     else if (!in_array(strtolower($d1->subtype),$dontattach))
     {
      if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
      if (isset($d1->id)) {$id = $d1->id;} else {$id = '';}
      $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d1->parameters[0]->value,strtolower($d1->subtype),$id);
      array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
     }

     if (isset($d1->parts))
     {
      foreach ($d1->parts as $j2 => $d2)
      {
       if ($d2->subtype=='GIF')
       {
        if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
        if (isset($d2->id)) {$id = $d2->id;} else {$id = '';}
        $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d2->parameters[0]->value,'image/gif',$id);
        array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
       }
       else if ($d2->subtype=='HTML')
       {
        $a = mail_service_html($mbox,$i,$d2->encoding,$d2->parameters[0]->value,$ii,$j);
        if (isset($a['css'])) {$email['css'] = $a['css'];}
        $email['body_xml'] = $a['xml'];
        $fallback++;
       }
       else if ($d2->subtype=='JPEG')
       {
        if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
        if (isset($d2->id)) {$id = $d2->id;} else {$id = '';}
        $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d2->parameters[0]->value,'image/jpeg',$id);
        array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
       }
       else if ($d2->subtype=='PLAIN')
       {
        $a = mail_service_plain($mbox,$i,$d2->encoding,$d2->parameters[0]->value,$ii,$j,$k);
        $email['body_clean'] = $a['xml'];
        $email['body_text'] = $a['plain'];
        $fallback++;
       }
       else if ($d2->subtype=='PNG')
       {
        if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
        if (isset($d2->id)) {$id = $d2->id;} else {$id = '';}
        $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d2->parameters[0]->value,'image/png',$id);
        array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
       }
       else if (!in_array(strtolower($d2->subtype),$dontattach))
       {
        if (!isset($email['attachments'])) {$email['attachments'] = array();}
        if (isset($d2->id)) {$id = $d2->id;} else {$id = '';}
        $a = mail_service_attachment($mbox,$i,$ii,$j,$d2->parameters[0]->value,strtolower($d2->subtype),$id);
        array_push($email['attachments'],$a);
       }
       $j++;
       $k = 1;
      }
     }

     $ii++;
     $j = 1;
     $k = 1;
    }
   }
```